# CURL авторизация и размещение поста в VK

Tags: php, вконтакте, curl

Друзья , помогите пожалуйста! В общем с авторизацией по средствам php curl все получилось. Проблема с отправкой поста на стену пользователя так же по средствам curl, не могу понять как извлечь хэш пользователя из al_wall.php для последующей отправки поста на стену... Решение через API не интересно.

Comment: Вроде бы на странице есть тег `script` содержащий `Profile.init` в нем есть поле `post_hash`.... вроде оно

Comment: Я не совсем понял на какой странице...Вот сейчас ковырял и не нашел ничего подобного(

Comment: На странице юзера на главной... прям в `html` разметке